# Facebook on pc missing deactivation option

Tags: facebook

I am trying to deactivate my Facebook account using the official guidance [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/214376678584711) but I don't see deactivation/deletion options. I am including a screenshot for your reference. The deactivate/ delete option should be at the bottom of the page. [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a workaround: just click on [this](https://www.facebook.com/deactivate_delete_account) link to deactivate or delete. But this still doesn't explain what the typical way to deactivate is.

Comment: How do you found the link?